# Nested divs with display:table style are not strech to 100% height in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, nested, css-tables

I have a responsive layout, which works perfectly in FireFox, Chrome and Opera but not in IE. It stretches vertically and horizontally in those 3 modern browsers but not in IE. It's based on `display:table` css technic.

This my code:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header"> header header header header header </div>
    <div id="contentWraper">
        <div id="content">
            <div id="columnsWraper">
                <div id="leftPanel">left panel <br /> left panel <br /> left</div>
                <div id="rightPanel">right panel</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">footer</div>    
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body { height: 100%; background: gray; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#container { display: table; height: 100%; width: 100%;}
#header { height: 0%; display: table-row;}
#contentWraper  {height: 100%; background: lightgray; display: table-row;}
#content {height: 100%; background: lightgray; display: table; width: 100%;}
#columnsWraper    {height: 100%;  display: table-row;}
#footer { height: 0%; display: table-row;}
#leftPanel { background: wheat; width: 100px;  display: table-cell; }
#rightPanel { background:yellowgreen; display: table-cell; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wftHq/6/

It works also in IE until I use nested divs with "display:table" style. I had to use it, otherwise "header" was only 100px wide (the width of "leftPanel"). 
Only in IE "leftPanel" and "rightPanel" doesn't fill the 100% height. Is there a way to fix it in IE ? Does anyone know how to change my code to work in IE. I'm trying to avoid using javaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Without using "table style" and works on IE:

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="header"> header header header header header </div>
    <div id="contentWraper">
        <div id="content">
            <div id="columnsWraper">
                <div id="leftPanel">left panel <br /> left panel <br /> left</div>
                <div id="rightPanel">right panel</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
    <div id="footer">footer</div>    
</div> 

</body>

</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
html,body {
    background:gray;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

#container {
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
}

#header {
    background:#FF1493;
    top:0;
}

#footer {
    background:#87CEEB;
    bottom:0;
}
#header, #footer {
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1.5em;
}

#contentWraper {
    position: absolute;
    background: black;
    width: 100%;
    top: 1.5em;
    bottom: 1.5em;
}

#content {
    background:lightgray;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

#leftPanel {
    vertical-align: top;
    background:#F5DEB3;
    width:100px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

#rightPanel {
    background:#9ACD32;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    left: 100px;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```